# How to find intersection of sets using Archimedean principle?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, inequality

> Given $K = \mathbb N - \{0,1\}$ for all $n \in K$ and $B_n=\{x \in \mathbb R:\frac{1}{n}\le x<1+\frac{1}{n}\}$. Find $\bigcap_{n\in K}B_n$.

It is evident to me that the intersection is the interval $\big[0.5,1\big)$. In order to prove it I know I need to prove two directions.

First, $\bigcap_{n\in K}B_n \subseteq \big[0.5,1\big)$. If we plug in $n = 2$ then:
$$
0.5\le x <1.5
$$
and of course there're $x$ in $\big[0.5,1\big)$ when $n=2$. If $n$ is very large then:
$$
0<x<1
$$
so still there're $x$ in $\big[0.5,1\big)$.

I'm not sure how to do the second direction especially when the Archimedean principle is should be used (the principle is that for all $x > 0$, there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $0<\frac{1}{n}<x$).

I think we need to substitute maybe $1+\frac{1}{n}$ as $\alpha$ and then somehow redefine $x$ but I'm not really seeing this.

Comment: $1 \not \in [0.5, 1)$ but $1 \in B_n$ for all $n$.  So $1 \in \cap_n B_n$.  So $\cap_n B_n \ne [0.5, 1)$

Comment: @fleablood so $\bigcap B_n = [0.5,1]$?

Comment: Yes. One way to note this is to write $B_n=X_n\cup Y_n$ where $X_n:=[1/n,1)$ and $Y_n:=[1,1+1/n)$ and note that $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are disjoint with $X_{i+1}\supseteq X_i$ and $Y_{i+1}\subseteq Y_i$; now use distributive laws of $\cap$ over $\cup$.

Comment: This gives $\cap B_n=(\cap X_n)\cup (\cap Y_n)=[1/2,1)\cup\{1\}=[1/2,1]$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas but how to I prove that $[0.5, 1] \subseteq \bigcap B_n$?

Comment: Note that for all $n\geq 2$ and $x\in [1/2,1]$, we have the following chain of inequalities: $$\frac 1n\leq\frac 12\leq x\leq 1\leq 1+\frac 1n$$

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I tried substituting parts of the inequality, for example, because $0.5 \le x$ then $x = 0.5 + y$, then $0.5 + y\le 1 +\frac{1}{n}$ then $0\le y\le 0.5 + \frac{1}{n}$ but it's not really getting me somewhere

Comment: What are you talking about? The above chain of inequalities in my previous comment explicitly shows that for all $x\in [1/2,1]$, we have $x\in B_n~\forall~n\geq 2$, hence $[1/2,1]\subseteq\bigcap\limits_{n\geq 2} B_n$, which is what you wanted to show.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas I'm just wondering why the exercise had the tip to use the fact that for all $x>0$ there exists $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $0< \frac{1}{n}<x$